# How to make the brackets around years of cited papers to be () instead of []?

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using the `hyperref` package, and every paper I cite looks like Smith [1985], but I want it to be Smith (1985). Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `hyperref` has nothing to do with this. Are you using `natbib`?

Comment: Hi, thank you! Indeed, I am using `natbib`.

Comment: Load the `natbib` package with the option `round`.

Comment: Thanks @Mico, how do I exactly do that?

Comment: @splinter - `\usepackage[round]{natbib}` (see also @egreg's answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `round` option to `natbib`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{smith1985,
  author={Smith, John},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=1985,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\citet{smith1985}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The `filecontents*` environment is used just for making the example self-contained. Use your own `.bib` file.

[image]